# How can I adjust my grid template after I put grid-area in CSS?

Tags: css, css-grid

After I learned CSS Grid Area, I'm confused, what should I do if I'm going to change size for my grid can after I put `grid-area`? what I should most concern is a rows or columns

Code:

```css
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 2.5fr;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 200px 60px;
    grid-template-areas: 'header header header'
                         'sidebar nav content'
                         'sidebar nav content'
                         'footer footer footer';
}
```

Output:
[image]

Note: My english is not really good but I need help.
I'm trying to change my `grid-size-template` after I put `grid-area`.
I expect to understand about this thing.

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question, can You try to use translator.

Comment: Also provide your code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I assume that you wanted to update your grid-area size. You already specified it in grid-template-columns; changing the value should change the size. Btw, its better to paste your code here since the image host can be inaccessible at any moment, and its easier for us to help you :)

Comment: Here's a great resource for CSS Grid. You may be looking for the `grid-template-columns` / `-rows` section, or `grid-auto-flow`. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/